How to use Shortcuts app to mute/unmute MS Teams from anywhere (globally)?
The standard keybinding for MS Teams mute toggle is ⌘ShiftM. However, it only works if Teams is the current focussed application. So when I'm working on a document or typing notes in another app, I have to switch to the application and then toggle mute.
Is there a way to use Shortcuts to make a global mute toggle for MS Teams?

You are basically asking for ways for  external scripting the MS Teams. Given that the possibility of microsoft implementing Applescript is low, I think the difficulty would vary depending on how object-oriented it is written...
